# Текстовый редактор Wordpress удаляет/добавляет тэги, удаляет атрибуты, меняет разметку html

Tags: php, html, wordpress

При добавлении html разметки непосредственно в текстовый редактор Wordpress для статичных страниц возникают такие сложности:

1. Удаляются или добавляются теги `p`
2. Удаляются атрибуты `a`
3. Меняется разметка html - меняется вложенность тегов, например из ссылки `a` выносится все содержимое, например `div`

В `functions.php` добавила

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
```

Но это не помогает, как ожидается.

Плагины не использую.

Как правильно настроить текстовый редактор wordpress для корректного отображения верстки?

**UPD**

Добавляю:

```
<div id="collapseOne" class="collapse " role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
      <div class="card-block">text</div>
</div>
```

После удаления:

```
<div id="collapseOne" class="collapse ">
      <div class="card-block">text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

wpautop отношения к вопросу не имеет, он заменяет два Enter на `<p>` и одиночный Enter на `<br>`.

Сказанное выглядит странно. WordPress так себя не ведет. Для проверки был создан чистый сайт c последней версией WordPress и темой Twenty Seventeen. Вот код новой страницы, созданной в режиме Text:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот ее отображение в браузере:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сама тестовая страница доступна [здесь](http://test3.kagg.eu/so676677/).

Comment: как запретить удаление у тегов атрибутов `role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne"` ?

Comment: а полностью тег можно, чтобы не гадать?

Comment: обновила вопрос

Comment: обновил ответ - все отображается на 100%

Comment: да, ваше решение работает, но мне почему-то не помогло. сделала просто страницу `page-name.php` и в ней вся верстка корректно отображается. т.к. эта страница статичная, такое решение вполне подходит. спасибо за помощь